# Coordinates of all Diagonal Elements from a Point

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists, diagonal

I have a 2D list like this.

```
            [[0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 3],
            [0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 5],
            [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1],
            [2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 5, 1, 6, 0, 2, 0],
            [2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

For a particular problem, there is a portion in which I have to find all the coordinates from a given coordinate vertically, horizontally, and diagonally.
Suppose the given coordinate is (4,2)->(row,col)=5. From (4,2) I have to find all the coordinates **vertically which will be **(0,2) (1,2)...(5,2)**. **Horizontally (4,0)...(4,7)**. I solve it for vertical and horizontal But I can't figure out the diagonal problem. **(3,1)..(5,3)**

```
def connected_values(arr,val,coord):
    #arr->[[2d list]]
    #coord -> given coordinate->(4,2)
    a,b=coord
    list=[]

    # arr=np.array(arr)
    for i in range(len(arr[0])):
        for j in range(len(arr[1])):
            if i==a and j==b:

                for k1 in range (0,i):
                    list.append((k1,b))
                for k2 in range(0,j):
                    list.append ((a,k2))
                for k3 in range(i,len(arr)):
                    list.append((k3,b))
                for k4 in range(j+1,len(arr[0])):
                    list.append((a,k4))

    return list
```

Advance thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I guess I have figured it out.

```
row,col=len(arr),len(arr[0])
            valid_x,valid_y=range(row),range(col)
            for d1 in range(row):
                if d1-a+b in valid_x:
                    list.append((d1,d1-a+b))
            for d2 in range(row):
                if a+b-d2 in valid_y:
                    list.append((d2,a+b-d2))
```